# Sub directory to ask for password not main directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have a folder which is in my public_html folder that I want to password protect.

In that folder I have an .htaccess file which points towards a password file outside of the public_html folder.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please Log In"
AuthUserFile "/home/mysite/.htpasswds/public_html/admin/passwd"
require valid-user
```

So when I visit mysite.com/admin/

It asks for a username and password this is what I need it to do!! :)

But when I visit mysite.com/

It still asks for a username and password.

And I don't want visitors to have to click cancel when they visit the site.

How do I make it that the username and password is only asked when the sub-directory is visted?

Comment: Put the .htaccess folder in the directory you want protected, not at the top level.

Comment: @Jay Blanchardquota "In that folder I have an .htaccess "

Comment: @splash58 Hard to know for sure because the result would indicate that is not the case.

Comment: @Jay Blanchardquota in your words there is truth